# How can I get my network adapter to automatically connect to open networks on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm using Ubuntu Linux LTS 20.04.3 on my laptop. I had a stupid idea to get free wifi on road-trips: I have an Alfa wireless adapter with 2.4/5 gigahertz support. It has some pretty great range, so I thought it would be cool if it could automatically connect to any open networks with the best connection, so that maybe it would be just good enough to watch a YouTube video by buffering. Is there any way I can get it to automatically connect to the strongest open network in range? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It'll automatically connect after having been connect to it once explicitly. No OS connects automatically to unknown open networks and that is for a very good reason.